# Symfony 3 on AWS Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, apache2, symfony

i`m already stuck for almost two days with this issue.

I installed and created new project of Symfony3 on AWS/Ubuntu. Configured all the requirements(didn`t do anything with apache2 so far)

project is created in /var/www/html/{directory-name}

Using documentation/tutorials i see people going to 52.xx.xx.xx/{directory-name}/web and they are getting into welcome screen. While I only get to see directory files&folders

[52.xx.xx.xx/{directory-name}/web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BxRx.png)

when going to 52.xx.xx.xx/{directory-name}/web/app.php or app_dev.php or config.php it`s all works.

[52.xx.xx.xx/{directory-name}/web/app.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS1mb.png)

Using the next video/text tutorials, they are pasting this code

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HomeController
{
/**
 * @Route("/home")
 */
public function showAction()
   {
    return new Response('Hello');
   }
}
```

going to 
/{directory-name}/web/home and it works for them all i get is this :

{Not Found

The requested URL /web_app/web/home was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 52.xx.xx.xx Port 80}

Maybe i miss understood the whole thing about Symfony3, looking for help!

Comment: where do you get this error?

Comment: And who are them and does it work for them in browser?

Comment: Found the problem, should have used 52.xx.x/{directory}/web/app.php/home instead of 52.xx.x/{directory}/web/home what a small mistake drove me crazy for a whole day

Comment: Good it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh okay i think i found where the problem was. I should have used 52.xx.x/{directory}/web/app.php/home instead of 52.xx.x/{directory}/web/home as i didnt rewrite it in apache2 virtualhost

Answer (score 0):

in your Apache config you should have this:

```
DocumentRoot "/{path to symfony project}/web"
...
<Directory "/{path to symfony project}/web">
```

You are specifying the wrong web folder...